# Why should I have to precompile assets everytime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Whenever I add any type of asset (Javascript, image or CSS file, whaterver), it gives me error to precompile first by adding `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(  )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb`. What should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: try add string `config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)` in your `config/application.rb` and if you have custom fonts also `config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/` there

Comment: Why is this error? Can you please explain this error?

Comment: I'll explain if you want

Comment: yes Please @RichPeck

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused when you explicitly reference assets which aren't in your asset pipeline. Specifically:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, "file" %>
```

The issue is that you're calling a file which *has* to be compiled outside the [normal scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) of the asset pipeline (concatenating all files into `application.js`/`application.css`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
```

The above creates a *single* `application.js` file which any referenced files (eg `jquery`) are placed.

---

This works well, however, if you have `file.js` which you're referencing individually, you'll end up with massive issues if Rails cannot find it. Thus, you are prompted to add the file to `assets.rb`:

```
#config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(file)
```

you *only* need to refer to explicitly referenced files with `assets.rb` (you don't need to reference images etc).